# Problem with sorting matrix groups in SSRS

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssrs

I've hit the following issue in SQL Server 2005 Reporting Services

This is a slightly odd and complicated situation: I have a table containing various groups and within each group is also embedded a matrix. The rows of each matrix are sorted by a different field to their group expression. So far, so good.

The problem arises in the table header: it needs to mirror exactly the format of each group to give a "Grand Total" type functionality. I've copied exactly the matrix from the table's groups, but it refuses to sort the data correctly. I've tried changing the sort direction - even removing the sort altogether - but it makes no difference to the order in which the data is displayed.

Since I originally hit this issue, I've found a workaround involving simply grouping by the "sort" column - this works since it was only a calculate field created to sort the matrix groups.

Would still be interested to know why this is an issue for a matrix in the table header but not the group header.

Any ideas?